# Refresh admin authentication token

Tags: shopware6

Is it possible to refresh the admin authentication token? At the current default implementation it expires after 10 minutes.

```
        $header = ['Content-Type' => 'application/json'];
        $authJson = json_encode([
            'grant_type'    => 'client_credentials',
            'client_id'     => $key,
            'client_secret' => $secretKey,
        ]);

        $auth = new GuzzleRequest('POST', '/api/oauth/token', $header, $authJson);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot refresh tokens of `client_credentials`. Just fetch a new token instead.

Comment: If it is not possible to refresh tokens, is there a way to increase the expiration time instead?